# Returning indexes for all subarray in 2D array that contains n

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to find a way to return the indexes of ALL subarrays that contain the number `1`. For example, in this 2D array:

```
ary= [[0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 1, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

My goal is to return `[1, 2]`.

Using the following:

```
ary.index(ary.detect{|xyz| xyz.include?(1)})
```

returns only `1`, which is the first subarray with `1` detected.

How can I get all the indexes of the subarray that contains `1`?

Answer (score 0):

```
ary.map.with_index {|sub_ary, i| sub_ary.include?(1) ? i : nil}.compact    
=> [1, 2]
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

﻿﻿Use `select`

```
irb(main):013:0> ary.select {|xyz| xyz.include?(1)}.map {|i| ary.index i}
=> [1, 2]
```

Comment: If `ary = [[0,1],[0,1]]` this will return `[0, 0]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ary.each_index.select { |i| ary[i].include?(1) }
  #=> [1,2]
```